# How can I enjoy or avoid designing every web application I make?

Tags: web-applications

I know this sounds silly, but I'm having huge problems (ok, not that huge, but still...) problems when I get an idea for a web project, small or big. The instant turn off is when I remember that I have to code the html/css by hand again and again. I like programming a lot more that designing web sites, and I simply don't enjoy designing them as much as I enjoy programming them.

With that said, I also prefer simple and minimalistic designs. What is your approach in web design, how do you make it enjoyable (at least a little bit)?

Comment: Good question, IMO. I love writing Twitter apps, but I hate designing a UI for them, which is why I've yet to make any available to the public.

Comment: Why not use a CMS?  Seems like that would be a solution for you.

Comment: @JB King: I'm mostly developing custom web applications, and not sites for companies/organizatins, blogs or anything that is "generic".

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have any/like any prefabricated templates, **team up** with someone. Share your idea with a designer, and work together on the project.

Comment: Funny how I always end up helping them on the application backend, and I never asked for a return favor. Good idea! :)

Answer (score 4):

I use [prefabricated HTML/CSS templates](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=css+templates).  Or I create my own and reuse those.  But I try not to reinvent the wheel each time.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't really clear when I said that I do it "again and again". The problem is that basically every application I create *needs* a different design, different strategy in structuring the site. Reusing templates would be the solution for generic sites about companies, organizations etc., or for blogs. Maybe I'm wrong about this :\

Comment: But many websites have a common overall structure. If you can capture that structure and style in your HTML/CSS template, the only thing that changes is the content.  And if you have a sensible design for your template, it becomes fairly easy to make structural changes if they are needed.

Comment: Most sites are pretty standard, but for the new and mind-boggling ideas that would bring in loads and loads of money, you usually need that little something extra to take off. And even though you can get very far with (small modifications to) templates, you will never, by definition, become truly unique.

Comment: @Tomas: For those kinds of applications, I recommend enlisting the help of a designer who understands CSS and HTML, and can create a really nice template that is independent of the application proper.

Comment: Also, the functionality is equally important as the design. If a user can understand and make use of valuable functionality in an application, that is more important than the best possible web page design, as millions of users of Facebook can attest.

Answer (score 1):

I do some XHTML/CSS myself. Reuse is the key. Most designs are pretty common: header, columns, footer. Create some generic designs which you get to know, modify and reuse. Use comments in your CSS, that way you'll find things to modify easier.

If you organize your toolset, most of your XHTML/CSS work will be modifying existing code and not writing them by hand from scratch.

If that doesn't work, delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following 3 possibilities as good candidates in your decision:

1.) Use CMS (It's simple and affordable)

2.) Give your design tasks to a university where for a small ammount students would be willing to do this for you and you could make payment as scholarship and organize the work on the project as a race between students to find the best designer. You don't have to pay taxes after scholarship payment, students are willing to do the job for a very small ammount (students are the poorest people in the world) and from 10 candidates you could choose the winner (the best in your taste)

3.) Go to a Freelancing site and open this project. Freelancer designers would try to bid for lesser and lesser prices, shorter and shorter timeframes and the winner would be the Freelancer who provides the best solution for the lowest price. However, in most cases, the cheapest person and the provider of the best quality is not the same person, in this case, you must decide how important is the cost and how important is the quality for you.

Answer (score 0):

I find that enjoying any kind of development involves solving challenging problems 10% of the time. The other 90% of the time is tedious repetition of patterns. Over time you refine your patterns, your templates, your process, etc so that you can avoid the tedious parts where possible.

The bottom line though is usually you have to trudge through the tedious parts long enough to figure out how to avoid them, most new developers simply wont appreciate frameworks that generate code/automate design because they dont understand what hand-coding is being saved, etc.

Keep at it, I am sure you can optimize your process to reduce hand-coding html/css where possible. I dont think there is a good magic framework to remove this work. Pay your dues and you wont regret it.